# How to Nummerate different cell content in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, numbering

I have a list like the following:

```
Anna 
Carl 
Bert
Carl 
Bert 
Anna 
Doris
```

I Would like to have a function, which fills the neighbouring cells with a numerical index to the names.

```
Anna   1 
Carl   2
Bert   3
Carl   2
Bert   3
Anna   1
Doris  4
```

My solution up to now is to manually generate an index table somewhere in the sheet. And then assign the numbers with index.

I think this should be possible to be done in one direct step.

There should be something like a function:
 MyRankInDuplicateFreeList(comparisionValue; DuplicateContainingList)

Answer (score 1):

With data in column **A**, in **B1** enter 1.  In **B2** enter:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:A2,A2)>1,VLOOKUP(A2,$A$1:B2,2,FALSE),1+MAX($B$1:B1))
```

and copy downwards.

[image]

- If the name exists above, use the number from above
- If the name is new, use the next available number

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly, what I wanted.